# Multiple select box used selectpicker after append with ajax jquery not display properly

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

[inspect option value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nwyak.png)[image: Display like this]

Multiple selectbox append jquery not displayed properly .am used selectpicker with bootstrap select box , but appending ok ,displayed not properly , list displayed outside selectbox

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
$.ajax({

               url: '/pincode_filter',
               type: "get",
               data: {option: id},
               success: function (data) {
               // $(".test").empty();
                       $(".test").append('<option>Select</option>');
                       $.each(data,function(key,value){
                           $(".test").append('<option value="'+value['Pincode']+'">'+value['Pincode']+'</option>');
                       });
```

Comment: Show your `html` code, especially `<select>` tag with `.test` class

Comment: <div class="form-group ">
                                            <label class="col-3 col-form-label">Select Delivery Pincodes</label>
                                            
                                            <select id="pincode" name="pincode[]" class="form-control selectpicker" multiple="multiple">
                                            </select>
                                            
                                        </div>

Comment: So, there is no "test" class in that code. But you append something with ".test" applied. While you need something like this: ```$("select#pincode").append('<option>Select</option>');```

Answer (score 0):

just append on your select tag class
[check this for example](https://codepen.io/Unitarf/pen/ZEzOdOm)

like

```
 $(".selectpicker").append('<option>Select</option>');
 $.each(data,function(key,value){
 $(".selectpicker").append('<option value="'+value['Pincode']+'">'+value['Pincode']+'</option>');
                   });
```

Comment: But my case ,that is not working ,am used same class ,not not displayed ,so am inspect that selectbox ,its append actually like option ,but not display in UI

Comment: My need is actually ,when i select district automaticlaly append next multiple selectbox pincodes ,but append not working in pincodes

Answer (score 0):

According to selectpicker [documentation](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/) you need to refresh selectpicker elements after making some direct changes to them:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

So, assuming you have `<select class="test form-control selectpicker">` tag your java script `success` block, now can looks like this:

```
success: function (data) {
   $(".test").append('<option>Select</option>');
   $.each(data,function(key,value){
      $(".test").append('<option value="'+value['Pincode']+'">'+value['Pincode']+'</option>');
   });
   $('.test').selectpicker('refresh');
}
```